Datastream latency is very high and data cannot be synchronized
your textWhen I use Datastream to synchronize local data to Bigquery, I find that the total_latency metric starts rising from the 29th. I don't know how to fix it now. I can only post surveillance pictures. Can you take a look at it for me?
your textSystem latency looks normal
your textTotal delay is abnormal
your text(https://i.sstatic.net/rUDo0tUk.png)
your text(https://i.sstatic.net/LRusFb7d.png)
I checked the local synchronization database, and there was no delay. I don’t know how to check whether it is caused by back pressure on Bigquery and Datastream, or if it is caused by some other problem?
